# Browser with a modern UI

Tags: web-browser, user-interface

I'm in search of a modern web browser with a sleek and user-friendly interface. I've tried [Opera GX](https://www.opera.com/gx), but unfortunately, it caused my computer to slow down. I'm looking for a browser that strikes a balance between being lightweight and powerful, and is visually appealing. Can you recommend any browsers that meet these criteria and are also reliable and fast?

Edit: Should have a "neon" look.

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla Firefox: It is a popular browser with a modern UI. It offers a customizable interface and a range of features that make browsing faster and easier. It's also available on mobiles and it's open-source. Firefox is also incredibly lightweight, making it the perfect choice for low-end systems. It has been named the best alternative to [Opera Neon](https://www.opera.com/browsers/neon) by Alternativeto.net.

Link to website - [Website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)

Screenshot -
[image: Firefox New Tab]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/), personally. It's based in chromium, but the front-end is completely re-written. It can be a little buggy at times, but it's got a lot of really cool features and UI improvments.

Additionally, I haven't tried it since I don't have a Mac, but if you do maybe take a look at [Arc](https://arc.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Out of all the Chromium-based browsers the most lighweight one is just [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/) I'd say. The Gecko-based browsers are usually heavier.

Whether it matches your "visually appealing" part of the question or not is hard to say as everyone has their own taste. You should describe the desired looks accurately next time if you want an accurate